# what is the purpose of "self "

Tags: python-3.x, class, self

I have been learning manual neural networks using python3. I have seen using *self* after assignment operator such **_default_graph = self** in a method of a class. I know purpose of self in python that it refers to specific object created to the class but I cannot clearly understand its purpose that it is same as **self._default_graph** or it has different purpose. Also I cannot clearly understand **return self** purpose in a method of class.

```
class Graph():

def __init__(self):

    self.operations = []
    self.placeholders = []
    self.variables = []

def set_as_default(self):
    """
    Sets this Graph instance as the Global Default Graph
    """
    global _default_graph
    _default_graph = self
```

class for placeholder:

```
class Placeholder():
"""
A placeholder is a node that needs to be provided a value for computing the output in the Graph.
"""

def __init__(self):

    self.output_nodes = []

    _default_graph.placeholders.append(self)
```

class for variables:

```
class Variable():
"""
This variable is a changeable parameter of the Graph.
"""

def __init__(self, initial_value = None):

    self.value = initial_value
    self.output_nodes = []

    _default_graph.variables.append(self)
```

class for operation:

```
class Operation():
"""
An Operation is a node in a "Graph". TensorFlow will also use this concept of a Graph.

This Operation class will be inherited by other classes that actually compute the specific operation, such as adding or matrix multiplication.
"""

def __init__(self, input_nodes = []):
    """
    Intialize an Operation
    """
    self.input_nodes = input_nodes # The list of input nodes
    self.output_nodes = [] # List of nodes consuming this node's output

    for node in input_nodes:
        node.output_nodes.append(self)

    _default_graph.operations.append(self)

def compute(self):
    """ 
    This is a placeholder function. It will be overwritten by the actual specific operation that inherits from this class.

    """
    pass
```

and the basic graph looks like z = ax + b with a = 10 and b = 1 **z = 10x + 1** looks like this..

can any one me through this.... Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that `_default_graph` is a global variable: it is accessible from anywhere. Thus, `_default_graph = self` allows the whole program to know who the default graph is. When you construct e.g. an operation, typically you would have to pass in a graph object so the operation can know where to add itself; this way, everyone knows where to look for the current graph, and operation doesn't need to be told explicitly in its initialiser.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the clarification. is there any difference in using self. and using self after assignment operator such as above(I understand the point given by you for global variable here.). And also do you have some idea when to use ** return self ** in a method...

Comment: `self` is just the current object. `self.car.id` is "the id of _my_ car", and "self.car = new Car()` is "I just bought a new car; this here is *my* car." `president = self` is "*I*'m the president now.". `self.post(twitter)` is "*I*'m gonna post something on Twitter!". All of these `self` is the same: reference to the current object, as opposed to whatever is sitting in some other variable. `return self` is usually used for chaining: `self.yell().yell_some_more()` as equivalent to `self.yell(); self.yell_some_more` is possible only if the first method `return self`-ed.